# How to Send Password Forget mail to User upon activation of Account in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In our Application Users are created by Admin with a Random Password . So we send Activation Mail to User [(http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")](http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=eeeeeeeeeee%22)
We Use **devise_for :users**

```
def confirmation_required?
    true
end
```

So now We want when User activate his Account then automatically they send a Password Forget mail to him on his mail ID

Comment: Are you following any manual or book?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you

Comment: The `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby-on-rails-4` tags should be used to indicate that your question is about a specific rails version. Please edit and clean up your question - what specifically have you tried? What went wrong? You might want start by looking at the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos).